# when disk partitioning in ubuntu, wrong informations were detected

Tags: windows, linux, partitioning, mbr

when i check disk partition in ubuntu 9.04
using #fdisk -l
my friend show me like this.
i have 4 hard disks, but he didn't.. but only 3.
Was there anything wrong? when i installed linux and maked config?
(e.g> i have miss on setting disk partition matter)
and when see below result, the device sda2, sda5 start same address, end too.
is there anything wrong with my disk? i have seperated 4disks.. C:,D:, G:,H:
please teach me when you know about this matter.
thanks.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe9ffe9ff

Device     Boot     Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       10199    81923436    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           10200       19457    74364885    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5           10200       19457    74364853+   7  HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf16cf16c

Device     Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       10199    81923436    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2           10200       19457    74364885    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5           10200       19457    74364853+   7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the fourth *"mystery disc"* that you were seeing was the extended partition **container** for the logical partition `/dev/sdb5`. Your disc, when formatted with an MBR partition table, can only contain four primary partitions (`sdx1, sdx2, sdx3, sdx4`). If you want more partitions, one of the primary partitions can be made into an *extended partition*, which can contain *logical partitions* (`sdx5, sdx6, sdx7` etc.). Hopefully that explains the discrepancy.

The reason why `sdb2` and `sdb5` have the same start and end is because `sdb2` is the extended partition, and `sdb5` (the logical partition) fills the entire extended partition's space. Hope this helps!

(I tried to interpret your question the best I could, but I can always clarify my answer if you clarify your question!)

Comment: and if sda2 is extended partition, what's different sda1 with sda2 ?it seems to have no difference.

Comment: `sda1` is a primary partition that occupies sectors 1-10199, and `sda2` is the extended partition that occupies sectors 10200-19457 (if that's what you're asking).